# angularjs ng-repeat not working in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to access items in firebase using angularjs I got how many rows in firebase but not the values

**my code**

```
<ul class="next-days" >
                <li ng-repeat="item in val">
                   {item.name}
                    <a href="#43">
                        <p class="next-days-date"><span class="day">{item.text}</span> <span class="scnd-font-color">{item.price}</span></p>
                        <p class="next-days-temperature">{item.quan}</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**and my app.js**

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://qwertyuiop.firebaseio.com/values");
   $scope.val = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

[plunker demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/nZWjy1SP08Au6DJmoBYD/preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing a second `{` and `}`, so this works:

```
        <ul class="next-days" >
            <li ng-repeat="item in val">
               {{item.name}}
                <a href="#43">
                    <p class="next-days-date"><span class="day">{{item.text}</span> <span class="scnd-font-color">{{item.price}}</span></p>
                    <p class="next-days-temperature">{{item.quan}}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular needs double curly brackets to render value in view. You used only one curly bracket.

For ex.

Instead of `{item.name}` you need `{{item.name}}`

Here is [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wU8DPbXiwge0VDFS7YWG?p=preview).

Here is code

```
<ul class="next-days" >
  <li ng-repeat="item in val">
    {{item.name}}
    <a href="#43">
      <p class="next-days-date"><span class="day">{{item.text}}</span> <span class="scnd-font-color">{{item.price}}</span></p>
      <p class="next-days-temperature">{{item.quan}}</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```